# How to get checked checkbox while update from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I use checkbox list...but while m get update from gridview I can't get check checkbox... can anyone help me

```
 SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ims"].ConnectionString);
 Conn.Open();
 DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
 string query = "Select po_tax from purchase_order where po_id='" + Request.QueryString["po_id"] + "'";

 // ds1 = obj1.SelectQuery(query);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 SqlDataReader rdr;

 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (rdr.Read() == false)
 {
      //No Records
      rdr.Close();
      Conn.Close();
      Label3.Text = "No record found";
      return;
 }
 else
 {
      CheckBoxList chkbx = (CheckBoxList)form1.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
      rdr.NextResult();
      if (rdr.IsClosed == false)
      {
           while (rdr.Read() == true) [problem ocures here. it does not executes i.e does not go inside curly braces. why?]
           {
                ListItem currentCheckBox = chkbx.Items.FindByValue(rdr["po_id"].ToString());
                if (currentCheckBox != null)
                {
                     currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
                }
           }
      }
      rdr.Close();
      //string[] items = returned_value_from_db.Split(',');
      string[] items = sb.ToString().Split(',');
      for (int i = 0; i <= items.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
      {
           ListItem currentCheckBox = chkbx.Items.FindByValue(items[i].ToString());
           if (currentCheckBox != null)
           {
                currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
           }
      }
 }

 Conn.Close();
```

Comment: Might be better if you'll post the codes you used. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please try to clarify a bit?  What do you mean by "i can't get chek chekbox"?

Comment: in my project i use chekboxlist in my form...bt when i update from gridvie the pricouse insert value cant get.......mens wtevver i chek in chek box list cant get as a chekeked while update it....so my problem is i cant get cheked chekboxlist while update it

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code..hope it works

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ims"].ConnectionString);
 Conn.Open();
 DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
 string query = "Select po_tax from purchase_order where po_id='" + Request.QueryString["po_id"] + "'";

 // ds1 = obj1.SelectQuery(query);
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

 SqlDataReader rdr;

 rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 if (!rdr.Read())
 {
      //No Records
      rdr.Close();
      Conn.Close();
      Label3.Text = "No record found";
      return;
 }
 else
 {
      CheckBoxList chkbx = (CheckBoxList)form1.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
      rdr.NextResult();
      if (rdr.IsClosed == false)
      {
          do    //Dont place 'while' here coz u already used rdr.Read() before.
           {
                ListItem currentCheckBox = chkbx.Items.FindByValue(rdr["po_id"].ToString());
                if (currentCheckBox != null)
                {
                     currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
                }
           } while (rdr.Read())
      }
      rdr.Close();
      //string[] items = returned_value_from_db.Split(',');
      string[] items = sb.ToString().Split(',');
      for (int i = 0; i <= items.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
      {
           ListItem currentCheckBox = chkbx.Items.FindByValue(items[i].ToString());
           if (currentCheckBox != null)
           {
                currentCheckBox.Selected = true;
           }
      }
 }

 Conn.Close();
```

Comment: Does it goes inside the if(rdr.IsClosed == false) statement ?